# Vue js not rendering a custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm using this - http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/
Build a single js file with vue and that librarie, but the other code just in script tag. Component is registered. I put some data and it comes empty

[image]

It's just a code from "Getting started", nothing special. No one error in console, just empty node. The important thing: i'm using this inside another component with `inline-template` (upd: same even in root)

[image]

That's how file was created with webpack

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.Multiselect = require('vue-multiselect');
```

Then i just include compiled file and add script

```
<script>
    Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect);
    new Vue({
        el: '#vue-app',
        data: {
            options: ['one', 'two'],
            model: ''
        },
        created: function () {},
        computed: {},
        methods: {}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not enough context. Please show more of the code for the component

Comment: @thanksd I did it.

Comment: try `Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect.default)` instead

Comment: @thanksd You're my hero! Could you make it as an answer for topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'vue-multiselect'` module is meant to be imported like so:

```
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
```

By using [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), you assign `Multiselect` to be the value of the default export of the module.

But, because you use `require`, you are assigning `Multiselect` to be the module object with a `default` property containing the component's configuration options. The default export is not being resolved, and the value you're trying to access is in `Multiselect.default`.

You should either use `import`, or access the `default` property when defining the `'multiselect'` component:

```
Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect.default);
```